# Gitlab install on CentOS6

Tags: centos, gitlab, centos6

I installed gitlab on CentOS 6.4.

But when I restart gitlab-ctl, it does not work properly.

> Normal:
>
> [0/root]gitlab-ctl restart
>
> ok: run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 19847) 1s
>
> ok: run: logrotate: (pid 19856) 0s
>
> ok: run: nginx: (pid 19863) 1s
>
> ok: run: postgresql: (pid 19874) 0s
>
> ok: run: redis: (pid 19883) 0s
>
> ok: run: sidekiq: (pid 19889) 0s
>
> ok: run: unicorn: (pid 19894) 1s
>
> Mine:
>
> [0/root]gitlab-ctl restart
>
> ok: run: postgresql: (pid 42342) 0s
>
> ok: run: redis: (pid 42344) 1s

The installation was completed without errors.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should check logs ? is it 'start' will output same ?

Comment: @SAZ I checked the logs, but did not exist that I need.

Comment: @SAZ It is same output from 'start'

Comment: It's hard to say what is happening, if there nothing in logs, you should try debug with `trace` alike